# Expressing angular velocity of solid body

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, angular-momentum, rotational-dynamics, rigid-body-dynamics

[image: Rotating Disk]

**The problem:**

We have a circular disk of radius $R$ and mass $M$ that is mounted on a rotation axis that is not the axis of symmetry of the disk.  The moment of inertia with respect to the axis of symmetry of the disk, **$e_3$** is $I_3$. The moment of inertia with respect to one of the axis on the face of the disk is $I_1$.

I have two difficulties.

$1)$ How can I express $\omega$ in the axis system shown? The correction says that it will be $\begin{bmatrix} \omega cos\theta \\ 0 \\  -\omega sin\theta\end{bmatrix}$
However I do not see why $\omega$ has no component on the $e_2$ axis.

2)Once I have expressed $\omega$ and thus found $L_G=\begin{bmatrix} I_1\omega cos\theta \\ 0 \\  -I_3\omega sin\theta\end{bmatrix}$, how can I project this onto the axis that coincides with $\omega$?

Answer (score 1):

If you have the inertia matrix in body coordinates $$I_{body} = \begin{vmatrix} I_1 & 0 & \\ 0 & I_2 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & I_3 \end{vmatrix} $$

and a 3×3 rotation matrix $$E = \begin{vmatrix} \hat{e}_1 & \hat{e}_2 & \hat{e}_3 \end{vmatrix}$$

The then inertia matrix in world coordinates (along the axis) is

$$ I = E\,I_{body}\,E^\intercal $$

Comment: OK. I see that now. Any input on expressing $\omega$ in the axis system given?

Comment: Transform $\omega$ from world to local coordinates with $E^\intercal \vec{\omega}$